# node.js send email successful, but mail not found

Tags: email, node.js

I am using https://github.com/eleith/emailjs for my node.js application
After setting up the configuration properly, when I send email, I get the successful message in my log, but I do not see any mails either in the inbox or spambox :-(.. 
I using gmail, smtp.gmail.com, ssl:true, port:465.

```
email.send({...},function(err, message) { 
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error sending email : ', err);
        } 
        else {
            console.log('Email SUCCESSFULLY sent', message);
        }

^[[32m[2011-10-13 06:53:28.758] [INFO] console - ^[[39mEmail SUCCESSFULLY sent {
 attachments: [],
  html: null,
  header:
   { 'message-id': '<1318488805460.5532@Abcd-PC>',
     from: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
     to: 'yyyyy@gmail.com, ',
     cc: 'zzzzz@gmail.com',
     subject: 'Test mail from emailjs' },
  content: 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  text: 'Testing sending email' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code for my emails in node.js (using [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs))

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
  user: 'your@gmail.com',
  password: 'gmailPass',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  ssl: true
});

server.send({
  text: 'hello world',
  from: 'obama@state.gov',
  to: 'someone@else.com',
  subject: 'just a subject here'
}, function(err, message) {
  if (err) {
    // err
  } else {
    // ok
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am using... do not know what's going wrong.. if I provide wrong configuration, it throws error. but with right configuration, it says, "Email SUCCESSFULLY sent" in the log file. But ultimately I do not see any email coming to the "to" email id.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was comma(**,**) **"yyyyy@gmail.com,"** in the 'to' email. I was trying to add multiple ids separated by commas(,) and that created the problem..

In the documentation, they have mentioned though

```
**"someone <someone@gmail.com>, another <another@gmail.com>"**
may be it expects the email format to be in the form they mentioned.
```